# How to change cell movement in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

After pressing enter, is it possible to move the selection of the next cell as shown in the picture attached? Right now, when it reaches the 5th cell in the first column, and I press enter, it'll move to the 6th column. When I press enter, I want it to move to the 5th cell in the 2nd column or the 1st cell in the second column. Is this possible?

I understand I can click on it to move it, but this is for data entry, and I will save days if I don't have to keep clicking around.[image: Cell movement]

Comment: Select the entire range first.

Comment: No way (for the second) without VBA, but you can write code for `WorkSheet_SelectionChange`. The suggestion of @BigBen gives you the first and is much easier.

Comment: Although someone provided a code snippet as an answer, the basis of this question is not programming related. This would have been an appropriate question for [su].

Comment: @BigBen can I select and lock the range for multiple tables?

Comment: You can select multiple ranges, yes, and this will still work. Not sure what you mean by "lock" though.

Comment: @BigBen can I select the range for multiple tables at once, save the file, and then when someone else opens it up, they don't have to do it again.

Comment: I'd just define a name for the entire range. That way you can select it from the dropdown.

Comment: @BigBen then when you select that name from the dropdown, it'll automatically select the whole range?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks a lot! How do I add the names of the ranges to a dropdown? I'm trying to go through "data validation", and I chose "list", and entered the name of my range, but it doesn't select anything. Is this right?

Comment: I meant the dropdown right above cell A1.

Comment: @BigBen That worked!!! Thanks a lot. You want to put this into an answer so I can "accept answer" so you get points or whatever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select the entire range first,  <kbd>Enter</kbd> will traverse the range in the first manner.

If you want to use this approach for a multi-range selection, perhaps just name the selection, and then you can easily select it from the dropdown:

[image]

Comment: I had never noticed the dropdown there. I usually access through `F5`

Answer (score 1):

Ayou can right-click the tab, View Code and write something like this in an event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Selection.Row > 5 Then Cells(1, Selection.Column + 1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, what "tab" are you talking about though?

Comment: @Dinukaperera - If you right click the Worksheet Tab (usually says like "Sheet1" by default), you add the code in there. (As opposed to a Workbook Module)